# Hide Last DIV using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I had a bit of a look around on Google, but couldn't find anything that worked. How do I hide the last DIV using the following code...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` gives you an array of elements that matches the criteria. So you need to specify the element index. So you have to find the size of array and apply the style to `size-1`th element.

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var size = el.length;
el[size-1].style.display = 'none';
```

**UPDATE:**

here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCu4w/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Just retrieve the length and take the last one of the array (length minus one, as it is zero based):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
divs[divs.length - 1].style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery's `last()` method (http://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('div').last().hide();
```

Comment: He didn't say he was using jQuery.

Comment: And I recommended with using JQuery. He also didn't say anything about not using frameworks, did he?

Comment: He didn't tag jQuery, he said "using JavaScript" and said with "the following code".
So I doubt he uses jQuery.

Comment: As I said, I've just recommended to use JQuery, maybe he doesn't know the framework? Just a starter in JS? I'm not Akinator. :-)

Comment: @eav: will recommend using a >90KB `js library` for just this task? :)

Comment: damn... you 2 arguing well.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div:last").hide()
```

it may help you..

Comment: He didn't say he was using jQuery.

Comment: That is jQuery; OP is obviously using vanilla javascript.